# Multiline JSON is not parsing

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Error on console
 scala> var njson = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json("C:/Users/Onkar/Desktop/new.json")
    njson: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]

My JSON:

```
[{
"Name": "Onkar",
"Age": 24,
"Place": "Baramati"
}]
```

Comment: Not Working .. I even tried that as well

Comment: {
"Name": "Onkar",
"Age": 24,
"Place": "Baramati",
"Number": 7709526425
}

Comment: Are you saying that your file contains only `{ "Name": "Onkar", "Age": 24, "Place": "Baramati", "Number": 7709526425 }` and the code above didn't manage to load the data frame?

Comment: As explained in the first comment, spark json reader expects record (doesn't matter if multi-line or not) to be JSON record, not array - because it treats each key as a column - can't be done with array.
What did you expect to be the content of your dataframe after the read?

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: can you post your complete json file ?

Comment: spark version is 2.1.1 and my JSON is that much only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spark version `2.2.0` onwards parsing array of json object is supported. Lower version of spark parsing array of json object is not supported or not parsing properly.

Please check below code.

```
scala> spark.version
res47: String = 2.2.0

scala> "cat /tmp/app.json".!
[{
"Name": "Onkar",
"Age": 24,
"Place": "Baramati",
"Number": 7709526425
}]
res48: Int = 0

scala> val jdf = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json("/tmp/app.json")
jdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Age: bigint, Name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> jdf.printSchema
root
 |-- Age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Place: string (nullable = true)


scala> jdf.show(false)
+---+-----+----------+--------+
|Age|Name |Number    |Place   |
+---+-----+----------+--------+
|24 |Onkar|7709526425|Baramati|
+---+-----+----------+--------+
```

spark version `2.1.1` has some issue as its not parsing array of json object & This issue has been fixed in newer versions.

```
scala> spark.version
res2: String = 2.1.1

scala> val jdf = spark.read.option("multiLine","true").json("/tmp/app.json")
jdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string]

scala> jdf.printSchema
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: my version spark is 2.1.1 and scala 2.11.8 is there any problem with this ?

Comment: val jdf = spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("C:/Users/Onkar/Desktop/new.json").values)  This worked for me ..

Comment: spark 2.1.1 does not support .option()

Comment: I have updated answer, Please accept or upvote if this solution helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Parsing array of json object in spark 2.1.0 or 2.1.1 will not work & same issue has fixed in spark 2.2.0 version... why down vote ???

Comment: Spark 2.1.1 will support option().. that why are json is able to read only thing is not parsing

Comment: Thank U for ur help .. and I am new here .. I think by mistake I down voted u .. sorry for that ..

Comment: No problem..Thank you..